# Meaning of "blue blood"

Tags: terminology, culture

In a [series](http://hours.tumblr.com/post/67118928961/mellie-its-getting-tons-of-playthe-story-of-how) I heard the statement below. It praises a person as an attractive spouse to be picked by an upcoming politician. However, the speaker compares said person as contrasted by a blue collar worker making his living with manual labor and living far less than wealthy.

> Your blood was blue. Mayflower blue. D.A.R. blue.

I understand what the person tries to say but I notice that, according to my knowledge, it's an oxymoron. The refugees on the ship were anything but royal. Those were religious deviants (by the regime's standards, of course) and mostly poor, definitely commons. The American Revolution, which I assume it's a reference to, can't, by the very definition of the USA, be royal in any sense (as it's established in the constitution).

Has the speaker made a logical poof or am I unaware of additional meanings of the term "*blue blood*"? Or perhaps I'm mistaken regarding the historical aspects of the referred to events?

Comment: ... but the Mayflower colonists are the epitome of American history. Being able to trace your family back to the Mayflower arrival is a big deal and elevates one to a certain level of notoriety... You don't include the rest of the conversation about this, but if someone's trying to say that this person was a "true American" when they did something against the USA, that would make sense to me.

Comment: @Catija Please note that I understand **the intention** of the speaker. Also, please view the edit in a few seconds. I'll add a summary of the preceding subject.

Comment: I think it's self-evident. For instance, my grand-grandfather was a Communist Party member from about 1905, which made his offspring kind of "blue-blooded" in the Soviet system, while those whose granparents were part of the Tsarist elite classes were, on the contrary, forced to hide this part of their ancestral history. The reference frame of "blue blood" shifts in accordance with the situation. Of course, this "blue blood" was in no way formalized and often brought no real benefit. (0:

Comment: I had to look up [**DAR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughters_of_the_American_Revolution), but as soon as I found that *Daughters of the American Revolution (DAR) is a **lineage-based** membership service organization for women who are **directly descended** from a person involved in United States' independence.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question wasn't regarding what the speaker meant. I was wondering if the writers of the series made a historical poof or is there's a flexibility of the "blue blood" expression I'm ignorant of. Also, you should get +1 for the link to the text (I was considering a link to tv.com but didn't see the point - your contribution is great). Oh, I had to look up D.A.R too. Uncommon term?

Comment: Konrad: I'm BrE, so it's hardly surprising I'd never heard of DAR (and the actual collocation *D.A.R. blue* looks like a complete one-off). But I'm with @CopperKettle in saying the broad thrust of the meaning is self-evident once you see the full context. I think your problem here is that you need to take on board the extent to which English uses *metaphoric* language. Personally, I'd say that *all* language (not just English) is essentially "metaphor", and this is just a typical example of "metaphor piled upon metaphor". In short - don't assume every intended meaning is "literal".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll consider taking things less "literally"; you've got a point there. I'm kind of allergic to incorrect usage of terms, though, because it tends to catch on among uneducated people (i.e. majority, sadly) and then, poof! - suddenly **I am** the one who's wrong. E.g. I heard last year *let's do sale soon so we avoid killing the business on black Friday - let's hope for red one instead*. Clearly, the person relates *red* to good (Christmas) and *black* to bad (death) and I understand the **intended** meaning but it just sounds like the nails on the blackboard. And it catches on!

Comment: Just thought of this discrepancy: the "blue blood" is not "royalty" but "nobility".  One doesn't have to have descended from a king to have blue blood, just from a very old noble lineage, usually hereditary nobility (knighthood, e.g. is not inherited).

Comment: @Konrad: Perhaps that person was Chinese. They think of red as a positive colour, and perhaps they use it that way in normal speech. We have loads of "negatives" like *Black Friday, Black Monday, black mood, black sheep, accident black spot*, etc., but offhand I can't think of anything except *red-letter day* for a standard Anglophone "positive".

Comment: To expand on @VictorBazarov's comment: the descendants of some of the Mayflower immigrants rose dramatically in wealth and social position after a few generations. Despite their anti-royalist origins, some of the notable families adopted the manners and privileges of an aristocracy/nobility, notably an obsession with bloodlines.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Although oddly enough, red battery terminals are the positive ones.  That might come from an old misconception that current "came from" the positive terminal, though, hence the positive terminal was the "hot", "active" one.  I guess there's "red hot", too, but that's more about the heat than the color!  As for black=positive, I can only think of *in the black* (meaning profitable).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, the person wasn't Chinese. They were just uneducated regarding the term *black Friday*. It's a positive thing because the numbers in economical reports turn from red (negative figures were drawn in red, traditionally) into black (meaning an above break-even cash flow). But you're right that we should always regard that others may view things differently. In this particular case, the person was just ignorant. And totally unwilling to reconsider the word choice. :)

Comment: @Konrad: Bear in mind Black Friday was originally thus named by the *police* ([in Rochester, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Friday_(shopping)#Origin_of_the_term)), who I'm sure didn't give a damn whether the day was "in the black" for retailers (I assume they saw it as a "black day" for accidents, like an accident "black spot"). So etymologically it's a bit of an oddity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't aware of that fact. I'll make sure to keep it in mind and hat off for you, sir. Impressive and deep contribution as always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a slightly metaphorical, extended use of the definition you found about royal blood.  America does not have royalty, as you correctly point out, but being [descended from Mayflower settlers](https://www.themayflowersociety.org/), or being a member of the [Daughters of the American Revolution](http://www.dar.org/) is a sign that your family is a very old, established Anglo-Saxon family - i.e., that you are a member of an upper class akin to royalty.

Comment: It may mean you have a long lineage of American heritage, but I don't think "upper class akin to royalty" is part of the connotation. I've met people who had this kind of family tree; when it comes to social status, most of them were "average Joes".

Comment: Ah, so it's a double metaphor, right? First we use the term *blue blood* in the traditional meaning of nobility. Then, we reuse it as a metaphor for *well seen and respected*. So it's really: *Your blood was "blue"*, where *blue* part isn't really blue-royal-blue but blue-well-respected-blue. Awesome point. Do people generally know it's not blue as in royal but blue as in akin to royal?

Comment: @J.R.  Well, you're not *literally* or necessarily that way, to be sure!  Plenty of people who are Mayflower and DAR are just regular working people, as you say, but it still has the implication of "something special".

Comment: @KonradViltersten, now, mix in another metaphor, "blue collar" and you get a whole other shade of the meaning...

Comment: @KonradViltersten - That's a good observation about it being a double metaphor!  Royals do not literally have blue blood, and "American blue bloods" are not literally royalty.  I think Americans would understand the usage, since we don't have royalty *per se*.

Comment: @stangdon - I think "something special" is a good way to word it. I think "upper class" is a very misleading way to word it. "Upper class" implies something totally different, usually closely tied to income, wealth, and privilege.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Darn... I didn't see such an obvious pun... Shame on me! Well, in that case, I claim that usage of *blue blood* in a looser, non-royal sense will lead to confusion when mixed with *blue collar* because the receiver can't know how to interpret the blueishness...

Comment: @stangdon You are **WRONG**. You do have a king. You have a bunch of presidents but only one king. At least according to the commercial I saw a while back. And he was the original guitar hero.

Comment: @J.R.- No, they are not literally upper class, but that's the implication, since both have historically been associated with being "the right kind of people" - the kind that held high government and industry positions.  For example, a substantial fraction of the Presidents were Mayflower descendants - George W. Bush, for one, and his wife Laura Bush was a member of the DAR!  That, I think, is the kind of thing that people are implying when they talk about Mayflower/DAR types.

KonradViltersten - Ha!  Yes, we do have [The King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley).  And a Burger King!

Comment: @J.R. While I understand the point of using *blue blood* more flexibly to denote *something special* I oppose that usage on the same grounds I'm against using an image of Adolf Hitler to imply high quality (as conotated with German cars). It's understandable and technically correct but, boy-oh-boy, it collides with the historical aspects and cultural concepts in my head.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten we regularly use "Royalty" in the US to refer to a great many things that aren't actually royal... possibly most common is "Hollywood royalty" to refer to the creme of the Hollywood crowd.

Comment: @stangdon Oh, LOL! Literally. I actually laughed out (kind of) loud. You're getting a royal, blue +1.

Comment: @Catija That's news to me. I've heard *celebrities* but not *royalties*. I've heard that the former get a lot of **royalities** but that's a different word, hehe. I'm  an outsider only visiting US every few years, so I'll have to take your word for it, unless you'll be contradicted by someone else. Interesting to learn new facts, anyhow.

Comment: I can attest, @Catija is spot on about "Hollywood royalty," although the word _royalty_ in that context refers mostly to the way cinema megastars have such large, devoted followings. It's more about the buzz these people create wherever they go than about any ruling status they have. See [this article headline](http://www.forbes.com/sites/juyoungseo/2015/09/13/vacation-like-hollywood-royalty-at-the-best-luxury-hotel-in-santa-monica/), e.g.

Comment: @J.R. But, to some extent, that's the same sort of "royalty" meant in this usage. To me, a phrase like "Hollywood blue bloods" would evoke people like the Douglas family and the Baldwins.

Comment: @J.R, no really, several of the Mayflower families became immensely powerful and wealthy, to the point of being a would-be aristocracy. See the Wikipedia article on "Boston Brahmins" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Brahmin, and the history of the Winthrop family https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley–Winthrop_family. Your friends might have had a long pedigree, but I bet they would have been cut by the likes of the Winthrops or the Cabots.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant - I never said that _none_ of those families become wealthy or influential, I just think it's misleading to say that _"being descended from Mayflower settlers .. is a sign that you are a member of an upper class akin to royalty."_ Sure, it's a possibility, but I really don't think all the leaves in those family trees are now in the same boat.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a "literal" meaning of blue blood, implying **literal** royal lineage. But the US was founded on the concept of "[No More Kings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-9pDZMRCpQ)"... so in the US, "royalty" refers to the people who founded the nation and separated it from the European monarchies.

The first group who falls into that category is the group who came over on the Mayflower. As you say, they were coming to a new world to get away from persecution.  Being able to trace your lineage to the original Mayflower settlers does give you a sort of "royal" status. It may not translate to much in modern terms - it's unlikely to mean you've got a financial advantage but it's a point of pride for the people in those families and, to some extent, is something that many other Americans respect.

The second group mentioned is the [D.A.R.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughters_of_the_American_Revolution) or the Daughters of the American Revolution. These, again, are not a literal royal class but the families of the people who fought the American Revolution.

> The organization Daughters of the American Revolution (DAR) is a **lineage-based** membership service organization for women who are directly descended from a person involved in United States' independence.

So, it's ironically appropriate for us to give the term "blue blood" to someone descended from a person who did everything to fight against royal control of the US... and, thus, makes them "royalty" in the most American sense.

Comment: I still thing that the writers just made a mistake (a bit like the American and Chinese presidents talk over the phone and it's bright middle of the day outside both's windows, despite them being in each their own capitol). But I can't prove it, so I'll have to give it benefit of doubt and you +1.

Comment: They're using 'blue blood' in the way that Americans use the term.  That's not a mistake, even if it's different to the way that I (a Brit) would use it.